# Assigning Indexes of Two Lists Together in Python

Tags: python

I created two lists. One of them is for the names of notes, and the other one is for the frequencies of the notes.

In short, something like this:

```
note_name = ['A1','B1','C1']

note_freq = [55, 61.74, 32.70]
```

What I wanted to do is to assign these two lists indexes together so when I type an element of the list `note_name`, it prints the value of the corresponding index of the list `note_freq`. In short, I want to use the elements of the `note_name` like variables. For example, if I type `A1` in the program, I want the value `55` to be printed, or if I type `C1`, I want the value `32.70` to be printed.

I tried something like that, but it didn't work. It gave me `KeyError : 1`.

```
note_name = ['A1','B1','C1']
note_freq = [55, 61.74, 32.70]

for i in range (0,3):
    globals() [note_name[i]] = globals() [note_freq[i]]
```

Is there another way to do that?

Comment: You don't need `globals()` here

Comment: The better data structure in your case is Dictionary: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries . Dictionaries allow this: note['A1'] which would return 55...

Comment: Quick fix: `globals()[note_name[i]] = note_freq[i]` -- but as others have suggested, there exist better approaches

Answer (score 2):

Turn them into a `dict`:

```
note_lookup = dict(zip(note_name, note_freq))
```

Then `note_lookup['A1']` gets you `55`, `note_lookup['B2']` gets you `61.74`, etc.

Of course, if you don't need the individual `list`s, you could just define the `dict` directly and save some work:

```
note_lookup = {'A1': 55, 'B1': 61.74, 'C1': 32.70}
```

This is a much better option than trying to populate global variables by name; avoiding unnecessary pollution of the global namespace, and discouraging nasty `eval` (and equivalently in Py2, `input`) hacks. Just use `raw_input` on Py2 (`input` on Py3) which avoids the `eval`, and use what it returns as a key for `note_lookup`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), not two lists:

```
notes = {'A1': 55, 'B1': 61.74}

typed_in = raw_input()

print notes[typed_in] # this will raise an exception if there's no such entry
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need a map or dictionary:

```
note_name = ['A1','B1','C1']
note_freq = [55, 61.74, 32.70]

note = { note_name[i]:note_freq[i] for i in range(len(note_name))}

print note['A1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are a fundamental datatype of python

```
In [57]: notes = dict(zip(note_name, note_freq))

In [58]: notes['C1']
Out[58]: 32.7

In [59]: notes
Out[59]: {'A1': 55, 'B1': 61.74, 'C1': 32.7}
```

Unlike lists, the order of dictionaries are not defined.  If order is important as might be with notes, then check out [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).  Which is a dict but also has a defined order.

```
In [60]: import collections

In [62]: notes = collections.OrderedDict(zip(note_name, note_freq))

In [63]: for note in notes:
   ....:     print '%s - %s' % (note, notes[notes])

A1 - 55
B1 - 61.74
C1 - 32.7
```